# How can I install siege using cgywin?

Tags: node.js, siege

I am studying nodejs and mysql connection and I got an error in runnning the make command.

Here's my reference for my tutorial:

https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/node-js-mysql

I already installed cgywin and here's what i did

1. I go to the extracted latest siege file
2. I run this command `./configure`
3. Then `make`

But when I try to run the `make` I got this error:

```
JLC-Mark@JLC-Mark-PC /cygdrive/c/wamp/www/siege-3.1.2
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

What can I do with this error?

Thats all I hope you can help me.

And one more thing can you suggest a good reference for real time updates using node and mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the [actual siege utility](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/), which is a C program that is not on npm. Depending on your platform, the program may already be available via your package manager.

Comment: I checked the website and downloaded the latest siege but how can I install it or run using Windows?

Comment: Well, [according to the faq](https://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/#a03), you'd have to compile and run it under cygwin if you're using Windows....